# changing array inside the collection mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to change an array in my collection of users according to the id of an object I have in my array

it looks like this

```
_id:60a54bb0a5c5d25c9f4b83ea
email:"timotej"
pass:"$2b$10$hdvMb.PrcRmwNCqxcLpOmOLTvRTrMzHWAhPHWa4o4E.qOfuDTjeAm"
createdAt:2021-05-19T17:32:32.792+00:00
updatedAt:2021-05-23T11:32:37.882+00:00
__v:0
contacts:Array
0:Object
_id:"60aa3d3db9344014e5944291"
name:"contact1"
email:"contact1@mail.com"
phone:"0"
1:Object
_id:"60aa3d55b9344014e5944292"
name:"contact2"
email:"contact2@mail.com"
phone:"00"
```

Shema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,        
        required: true,
        unique: true
        
    },
    pass:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    contacts:{
        _id: {
            type: String,
            unique: true            
        },
        name:{
            type: String,            
        },
        email:{
            type: String
        },
        phone:{
            type: String
        }
    }  
}, {timestamps: true})  

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema) 

module.exports = User;
```

here is my code, I am trying to find the user by its email, and then the object in array contacts by its id and then update the contact.

```
const user = User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { email: mail.toLowerCase(), "contacts._id": req.params.id},
    { $set:{
      "contacts.$._id": req.params.id,
      "contacts.$.name": req.body.name,
      "contacts.$.email": req.body.email,
      "contacts.$.phone": req.body.phone,
    }
      
     },
    { multi: false }
  ).then((result) => {
    console.log("result : " + result)
```

the data in req should be ok, but nothing is changing in my db when i send request

Comment: your query looks good, by default this method returns an old document, have you confirmed it is changed in database directly?

Comment: how does the database know which number of the `contacts` array are you changing? (I mean `contacts[0]`, `contacts[1]`, etc... )

Comment: @ManuSampablo see this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array

Comment: I've done something similar to this in the past and instead of `User.findOneAndUpdate()` I used `User.updateOne()`. Give it a shot just to try

Comment: Yes, I looked directly in the database but no changes, @ManuSampablo I want to change contact with matching id "contacts._id": req.params.id"; i tried ``` updateOne()``` and its the same result, no changes were made

Comment: I don't get what you are doing wrong, everything looks ok. Check if you can make other DB operations to make sure the preoblem is just in that specific function, and try to `console.log(mail.toLowerCase)` just to check that it is not what is blocking your connection. You can also add an error parameter to be thrown if there is any.

Comment: other operations work fine, I added a hardcoded condition to make sure conditions are fine and I added catch function but it is not triggering any errors. I added my schema to the question.

Comment: the result returns  "nModified": 1, but nothing is changing in database